# CSS - How to center a DIV menu

Tags: html, css

As like the title, here is my case.
The header part is ok for me, i manage to center it, but the menu part, i just cant figure it.
This is the HTML Part:

```
<div id="container">
<div id="topcontain">
        <div id="header">

        <div id="logo">
                Logo Here
        </div>

        <div id="title">
            <h1> THE TITLE HERE</h1>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>

<div id="menu">

        <div id="menu_button">
            <a href="#"> HOME </a>
        </div>

        <div id="menu_button">
            <a href="#"> PRODUCTS </a>
        </div>

        <div id="menu_button">
            <a href="#"> GALLERY </a>
        </div>

        <div id="menu_button">
            <a href="#"> INFO </a>
        </div>

        <div id="menu_button">
            <a href="#"> ABOUT US </a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is the CSS part:

```
@charset "utf-8";

html, body {
margin: 0px;
padding: 0px;
border: 0px;
font-family:Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
background-color:#000;
}

#container {
width: auto;
margin: 0 auto;
padding: 0;
}

#container #topcontain {
margin:20px 0px 20px 0px;
height:120px;
border-bottom:#F90 solid 3px;
}


#container #topcontain #header {
height:120px;
background:-moz-linear-gradient(#ffe2a3, #ffc341); /* FF3.6+ */
background:-webkit-linear-gradient(#ffe2a3, #ffc341); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#ffffe2a3,endColorstr=#ffffc341); /* IE */


}

#container #topcontain #header #logo {

width:150px;
height:117px;
margin:auto;
float:left;
}

#container #topcontain #header #title {

width:auto;
position:relative;
margin: 0px 50px 0px 0px;
height:117px;
float:right;
color: #900;
font-size:20px;
font-family:Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;
}

#container #menu {

float:left;
width: 100%;
padding:0 auto;
background:#ffc341;
position:relative;
overflow:hidden;
}


#container #menu #menu_button{
margin:0;
width: 150px;
position:relative;
display:block;
text-decoration:none;
text-align:center;
background:#ffc341;
float:left;
font-size:18px;
color: #000;
border-right: #F90 thin solid;
}

#container #menu #menu_button a:link, #container #menu #menu_button a:visited{
text-decoration:none;
color:inherit;
}


#container #menu #menu_button:hover{
background-color: #F30;
color:#fff;
text-decoration: overline;  
}
```

Looking forward to your reply, thanks.

Comment: What's the problem **[here](http://jsfiddle.net/aSyr8/)** ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. it is semantically better not to use div for menu (instead use  followed by
2. it's wrong to repeat many times an id (instead use classes, or combine css selectors - for your html #menu-button is the same as #menu div).

Here the html + css corrected with the centered menu

```
   <html>
<head>
<style>
@charset "utf-8";

html, body {
margin: 0px;
padding: 0px;
border: 0px;
font-family:Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
background-color:#000;
}

#container {
width: auto;
margin: 0 auto;
padding: 0;
}

#container #topcontain {
margin:20px 0px 20px 0px;
height:120px;
border-bottom:#F90 solid 3px;
}


#container #topcontain #header {
height:120px;
background:-moz-linear-gradient(#ffe2a3, #ffc341); /* FF3.6+ */
background:-webkit-linear-gradient(#ffe2a3, #ffc341); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#ffffe2a3,endColorstr=#ffffc341); /* IE */


}

#container #topcontain #header #logo {

width:150px;
height:117px;
margin:auto;
float:left;
}

#container #topcontain #header #title {

width:auto;
position:relative;
margin: 0px 50px 0px 0px;
height:117px;
float:right;
color: #900;
font-size:20px;
font-family:Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;
}

#container #menu {
width: 100%;
padding:0 auto;
background:#ffc341;
position:relative;
overflow:hidden;
}


#container #menu li{
margin:0;
width: 150px;
position:relative;
display:block;
text-decoration:none;
text-align:center;
background:#ffc341;
float:left;
font-size:18px;
color: #000;
border-right: #F90 thin solid;
}

#container #menu li a:link, #container #menu li a:visited{
text-decoration:none;
color:inherit;
}


#container #menu li:hover{
background-color: #F30;
color:#fff;
text-decoration: overline;  
}

/*centered menu */
nav ul{
margin: 10px auto;
width: 755px;
}
</style>
</head>

<body
<div id="container">
<div id="topcontain">
        <div id="header">

        <div id="logo">
                Logo Here
        </div>

        <div id="title">
            <h1> THE TITLE HERE</h1>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>

<nav id="menu">
         <ul>
        <li>
            <a href="#"> HOME </a>
        </li>

       <li>
            <a href="#"> PRODUCTS </a>
        </li>

       <li>
            <a href="#"> GALLERY </a>
        </li>

       <li>
            <a href="#"> INFO </a>
        </li>

       <li>
            <a href="#"> ABOUT US </a>
        </li>
        </ul>
   </nav>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

The centering is obtained giving a specific width to the ul (it could have also been a div or whatever) and giving it an "auto" margin for right and left.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out my mistake and your solution. but... i found out that the menu part do not work on ie 7 & 8. Any suggestion?

Comment: Sorry, i forgot that <nav> is an html5 only tag. If you want to use the latest standard you should add some js that do the compatibility job (as http://modernizr.com/ ), or you use <div> instead of <nav> and change my css to: div#menu ul{
margin: 10px auto;
width: 760px;
}

Comment: Now the menu part works perfectly even in IE 7, i choose to use <div> for my menu part. But your code brings up another issue for me, which is the "topcontain" background is only available in firefox but not in IE (7,8,9). At first, i thought it was just some typo, so i double check it. Looks like its not the typo problem. Any suggestion or solution to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

well floating something will mean its taken out of the flow (somewhat) and just, as the title suggests, floating left.

try and remove it:

```
float:left;
```

So:

```
#container #menu {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #FFC341;
    float: left;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
}

#container #menu #menu_button {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #FFC341;
    border-right: thin solid #FF9900;
    color: #000000;
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
    font-size: 18px;
    margin: 0;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    width: 150px;
}
```

Comment: You should update your question, you don't want the menu centered, you want the menu items centered!!!

Comment: I would more than happy to correct my question, but where should i look into?

Answer (score 0):

You may try to modify the `container menu` in the css part

```
#container #menu 
{
margin:auto;
width:85%;
padding:0 auto;
background:#ffc341;
position:relative;
overflow:hidden;
}
```

Try this and comment here for any issues..

Answer (score 0):

Since the width for `#menu` is set as `100%`, it takes up the whole width of the parent element, i.e `#container`, whose `width` is `auto`, i.e the width of the window.

So, you need to set the width of `#menu` and align it to the center, by getting rid of the float and the following changes :

```
#container #menu {
    width: 755px; /* 151px x 5 elements */
    margin:0 auto; /* Instead of padding */
    position:relative;
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

and for the yellow background, just wrap your `#menu` around with a `#menuWrapper` div, and also as [Italy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1947677/itay) specified, `id` should be unique on a page. Use `class` instead.

HTML :

```
<div id="menuWrapper">
    <div id="menu">
        <div class="menu_button">
            <a href="#"> HOME </a>
        </div>

        <div class="menu_button">
            <a href="#"> PRODUCTS </a>
        </div>

        <div class="menu_button">
            <a href="#"> GALLERY </a>
        </div>

        <div class="menu_button">
            <a href="#"> INFO </a>
        </div>

        <div class="menu_button">
            <a href="#"> ABOUT US </a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS :

```
#menuWrapper {
    background:#ffc341;
}
```

Also, it's better to use `ul-li` elements for the menu items instead of `div`

Full HTML + CSS : [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rduKf/)